# how to use string searching syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the syntax of searching through strings? For example, I have this piece of code:

```
var ok = phone.value.search(/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/);
```

phone is a variable that is supposed to contain a phone number, and I know from context that this is supposed to make sure the inputted number has the format ###-####, but I don't know what the code within the parenthesis means or how it is evaluated. If someone has a link explaining how to use code like that I would especially appreciate it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(phone.value)` would probably be a better way to do that…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) object. The `^` matches the beggining of the string, the `\d{3}` matches 3 digits, the `-` matches a dash, the `\d{4}` matches for digits, and finally the `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the explanation. Something to get started with as I start exploring this :)

Answer (score 2):

That's a regular expression ( regex ),

[Regex One](http://regexone.com/) has a good guide on how to use them

Your regex says "beginning with 3 digits, then a "-" then 4 digits"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, and the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular expression, a whole world in itself.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, and the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is called a "regular expression" and as you say, they are used to ensure input matches a certain pattern.  I recommend you go somewhere like http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for further info rather than re-post data here.